# Do Vietnamese F-1 students have a reduced capital gains tax in the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, tax-treaty, vietnam

From what I know, F-1 students that need to pay capital gains tax in the US have a flat rate of 30%, "unless a tax treaty allows for a reduced rate" (according to the IRS). My question is, "does the US and Vietnam have any tax treaty that allows for a reduced rate, or are Vietnamese US-based students subject to the 30% rate?

IRS Source: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/the-taxation-of-capital-gains-of-nonresident-alien-students-scholars-and-employees-of-foreign-governments

Comment: Could you add a link showing reference to where your quoted statement comes from? Could make it easier to provide a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Added link.

Comment: Followup question - will you be in the US for > 183 days, for purposes of determining if you pass the test mentioned? If you are there less than that length of time, the gains would be sourced to Vietnam, only. As to the question on the US-Vietnam treaty, I am not familiar enough to provide a full answer, but this link looks informative. https://www.dfdl.com/resources/legal-and-tax-updates/tax-alert-the-income-tax-treaty-between-vietnam/#:~:text=As%20a%20part%20of%20the,Treaty%20or%20%E2%80%9CDTT%E2%80%9D).

Comment: Interesting to note that this is not a full tax treaty, but just an agreement / understanding, which has only been in place since 2015.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: that page says _signed_ 2015 but 'will enter into force when ratified'. And it's NOT listed at https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/united-states-income-tax-treaties-a-to-z or https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/tax-treaty-tables which I expect to be correct (although probably the only fully authoritative source is the Congressional Record or maybe Federal Register).